# using statement for multiple assignments to the variable

Tags: c#, .net, using-statement

I have a variable "pen" of type System.Drawing.Pen which is getting assigned multiple times in a particular method. I want to put it within "using" statement. How I can do that?

```
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Gray);
// some code which uses gray value
pen = new Pen(Color.Green);
// some code which uses green value
pen = new Pen(Color.Red);
// some code which uses red value
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) statement is only applicable for object with implement `IDisposable` interface. If the `Pen` implement `IDisposable`, then yes you can use the `using` statement.

Comment: Reassigning the variable defeats the point of `using`. Are you using an odd variant of C# where you have to pay for additional variables? If not, just have 3 separate ones.

Comment: `using Pen grayPen = new Pen(Color.Gray); using Pen greenPen = new Pen(Color.Green);` etc.? (If you're using an older version of C# than 8 you'll need the traditional style `using` blocks but the concept is the same: one variable per pen).

Comment: You can use 3 separate variables with the same name, with different scopes: `using (var pen = new Pen(Color.Gray)) { ... } using (var pen = new Pen(Color.Green)) { ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `Pen` implements `IDisposable` since it allocates *unmanaged resources* (`HPEN`) and thus in general case `using` is required.
In your current code you have *resource leakage*:

```
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Gray);

// some code which uses gray value

pen = new Pen(Color.Green); // <- from now on Pen(Color.Gray) is leaked

// some code which uses green value
pen = new Pen(Color.Red);  // <- from now on Pen(Color.Green) is leaked
// some code which uses red value
```

You can either use *predefined* pens (no `using` required):

```
Pen pen = Pens.Gray;

// some code which uses gray value

pen = Pens.Green;

// some code which uses green value

pen = Pens.Red;

// some code which uses red value
```

Or if you want to create `Pen`s manually, wrap them into `using`:

```
using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Gray)) {
  // some code which uses gray value
}

using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Green) {
  // some code which uses green value
}

using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red)) {
  // some code which uses red value
}
```